# Where do I find the "cd" command?

Tags: path, ubuntu-10.04, cd

I need to know to know the full path of the command "cd" in ubuntu 10.04. Can anyone please help me find it. For example the full path of the command "dir" is "File System/bin/dir".
-Thanks in advance

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` is one of the builtin commands of `bash` (or similar shells).

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/which` screws up on shell builtins; `type` is a better alternative:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```